# Bootstrap hypothesis testing p-value confusion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I missed one of the lectures in my stats class and there was one slide that I could not understand.

[image]

In this example where $p^* = \sum_{j=1}^n l{\{...}\}/B$, I'm more familiar with the l indicating the function as a likelihood function for MLE. However, what does the l mean in this case for bootstrapping?

Comment: If you look carefully, you'll see that's an "I", not a lower-case "L".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it was notated like this but what is meant is that you count the elements in the set that fulfills the condition in {}. That is, for

$p* = \frac{\Sigma_{j=1}^n I\{\bar{X}^*_j ≥ \bar{X}\}}{B}$

You count, how many $\bar{X}^*_j$ are greater or equal to $\bar{X}$. The typical notation in the statistical literature on bootstraps is:

$p* = \frac{\#\{\bar{X}^*_j ≥ \bar{X}\}}{B}$ where $\#$ denotes the counting operation.

From this knowledge, I infer that what is meant on the slide is that by doing $I\{\bar{X}^*_j ≥ \bar{X}\}$ you create a binary variable, like this:

$I\{\bar{X}^*_j ≥ \bar{X}\} = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{if } \bar{X}^*_j ≥ \bar{X}\\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Summing over this variable is a technical definition of counting.

Does this make sense for you?